# Jquery website translation triggered with .on() .off() events on different links

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this script:

```
function jqueryxmltranslator(event) {
// Jquery XML Translator
var language = 'hungarian';
$.ajax({
    url: 'lang/hu_HU.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            $("." + id).html(text);
        });
    }
});
};
$('.menu-item-152 a').on('click', jqueryxmltranslator);
$('.menu-item-153 a').off('click', jqueryxmltranslator);
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translations>
    <translation id="menu-item-112 a">
        <english>Portraits</english>
        <hungarian>Portrék</hungarian>
    </translation>  
</translations>
```

This will translate my website for the specific language by an extended XML file. It works fine, but the .off() not turning off the function. I don't know javascript. What's wrong with this code?

This is alternative, working solution, where I can turn it off the translation - It calls the original english line from XML...

```
$('.menu-item-152 a').on('click', function(e){ 
// Jquery XML Language Translator
var language = 'hungarian';
$.ajax({
    url: 'lang/hu_HU.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            $("." + id).html(text);
        });
    }
});
});

$('.menu-item-153 a').on('click', function(e){ 
// Jquery XML Language Translator
var language = 'english';
$.ajax({
    url: 'lang/hu_HU.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            $("." + id).html(text);
        });
    }
});
});
```

But this is just damn ugly solution!

Comment: There is most likely a JavaScript I18n library out there that would let you do this. Storing the translations in XML and attempting to read them out with JS into a JS-friendly format is adding an extremely high level of complexity to a problem that is already quite complex.

Comment: Thank You for your answer! Please re-visit my new question bottom of this page. It was too long to write here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18694936/1442219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `off` on something that you haven't called `on` for.  The `off` event just unbinds the element for the specified event and it doesn't look as though you've had an `on` for `.menu-item-153 a`.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

What you may want to do is store the `language` variable in the selected menu link as a data-attribute http://api.jquery.com/data/ and then you can reuse the function.

Perhaps similar to this:

```
function jqueryxmltranslator(event) {
// Jquery XML Translator
var language = $(this).data('language');
$.ajax({
    url: 'lang/hu_HU.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            $("." + id).html(text);
        });
    }
});
};

// add the listener to all menu <a> tags
$('.menuContainer a').on('click', jqueryxmltranslator);
```

and your html structure for the menu would be like this:

```
<div class="menuContainer">
<div class="menu-item-152"><a data-language="Hungarian">Hungarian</a></div>
<div class="menu-item-153"><a data-language="English">English</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You! It works great! However, It's still not turning off the function on the next link, just using the english line from XML. If it's possible to turn off, than we just simply don't need the english lines. Less file size.

Comment: Unfortunately the original HTML is getting replaced in the DOM by Hungarian/English/whatever and hence you need to have a reference to go back to the original state.  This means that you'll have to have an original copy somewhere (like currently in XML).  Either you have it in the XML or you could change the above javascript and add a sibling to each element that needs translating, hiding all the originals by adding a `hide` class to them and only showing the translated siblings. To turn off you could then remove all the translated additional elements and unhide the originals via javascript.